# action_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Ive been having many problems creating my first android app on eclipse.

I believe im coming close to minimising the errors.

However, i cannot seem to fix this:

[image]

Here is all of my code:

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.rikin.myfirstapp;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.rikin.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rikin.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are importing the wrong **R** (`import android.R;`). It should be `import your.package.appname.R;`

Comment: import com.rikin.myfirstapp.R just comes up as an error.

Comment: Does it give you a bunch of errors (really many)? That's good: you are on the right path. It's probably just a file name containing a not allowed character.

Comment: 6 errors now http://puu.sh/cnwMt/7759a85635.png

Comment: The last one does appear randomically. Try doing a Project clean. R should disappear. That's good, as I mentioned above. Then fix your filenames (only small caps, no spaces . and _ numbers not allowed at beginning). ALL your filenames, in every subfolder except gen, libs and bin.

Comment: clean and built, but still got the R errors. the unparsed error is gone.

Comment: OK, check if you have the R.java file (in /gen/your.package.appname), it should be gone.

Comment: no R files and i think all filenames are ok.

Comment: To rebuild your R file, fix your file names and/or check the references (**ids** must be unique and not contain spaces). Then Project/Clean.

Comment: http://puu.sh/cnxj6/7ad1974cdb.png
http://puu.sh/cnxkO/32ef05c8d5.png

it seems okay? what should i change? sorry im a real beginner.

Comment: It's OK. Try to restart Eclipse. By the way, make sure you regularly upgrade your SDK followed by a Help/Check for Updates

Comment: done all of this still problems :'(

Comment: Post you manifest file, too.

Comment: posted it. i hope we can resolve this :/

Comment: What happens if you try to lower your targetSdkVersion to (say) 18? Forgot to mention. Make suer your Project/Build automatically option is checked.

Comment: Still got the same errors.

Comment: At this point, try making a new project.